# Have Automator folder action pass a list of files to AppleScript

Tags: applescript, automator

I need to pass to a .jsx script (a Photoshop script written in JavaScript) a list of image files as arguments when they are added to a folder. According to the Adobe documentation, you can call a .jsx in the following way:

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS6"
    do javascript (file "/path/myPhotoshopScritp.jsx") ¬
        with arguments { "path/image1.jpg","path/image3.jpg","path/image4.jpg" }
end tell
```

I know that when a folder action workflow is triggered, the items that were added to the attached folder are passed to the workflow. But I have problems in referencing these items from AppleScript and dynamically compose the array you see in the last part of the script:

```
"path/image1.jpg","path/image3.jpg","path/image4.jpg"
```

I imagine it's a simple task, but AppleScript is not intuitive for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `run` handler:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    input
end run
```

Or if you need the input as a list of POSIX paths:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set l to {}
    repeat with f in input
        set end of l to POSIX path of f
    end repeat
end run
```

For a script saved directly in `/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts/`, use an `adding folder items` handler:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    added_items
end addin
```